# Android Code using Fragments with listView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

So my coding got a few problems in its fragment the line "super(FragmentDishcover.this, R.layout.listviewdishcover, LV_Dishcover);" goes red line. i copied most of its files on the net and got no idea whats "getLayoutInflater()" is for. i thought it a new class or something but well tell me if it its please.

my FragmentD.class

```
public class FragmentD extends Fragment {

    public FragmentD(){}

    private List<NavItemViewlistD> LV_D = new ArrayList<NavItemViewlistD>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_d, container, false);

        populateListViewD();
        populateListView();

        return rootView;
    }
    private void populateListViewD(){
        LV_D.add(new NavItemViewlistD("Trololololol", R.drawable.kittylogotemp, R.drawable.ic_paw_white, 10));
        LV_D.add(new NavItemViewlistD("booom", R.drawable.kittylogotemp, R.drawable.ic_paw_white, 20));
        LV_D.add(new NavItemViewlistD("ahahahaha", R.drawable.kittylogotemp, R.drawable.ic_paw_white, 30));
    }
    private void populateListView(){
        ArrayAdapter<NavItemViewlistD> adapter = new dListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewD);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private class dListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NavItemViewlistD>{
        private dListAdapter(){
            super(FragmentD.this, R.layout.listviewd, LV_D);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            View itemView = convertView;
            if(itemView == null){
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listviewd, parent, false);

            }

            return itemView;

        }

    }
}
```

this is my NavItemViewList.java

```
public class NavItemViewlist {
    private String title;
    private int image;
    private int icon;
    private int points;

public NavItemViewlist(String title, int image, int icon, int points){
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.points = points;
}
public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}
public int getImage(){
    return image;
}
public int getIcon(){
    return icon;
}
public int getPoints(){
    return points;
}
}
```

Comment: replace with getactivity() instead of FragmentD.this. and   private dListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayAdapter<NavItemViewlistD>[] LV_D){
            super(context, R.layout.listviewd, LV_D); change like this.
        }

Comment: getActivity() turns red :(

Comment: and also getLayoutInflater() is red

Comment: use context.getLayoutInflater()

Comment: sir ram it it just turns red :(

Comment: and its confusing do i use the getActivity() or the context?

Answer (score 0):

YOUR DOING IN WRONG WAY.i suggested you to not include adapter in fragment.use as separate class like this

```
           public class SampAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

/**
 * @param context
 * @param resource
 * @param objects
 */
public SampAdapter(Context context, int resource, Contact[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}
```

}

and set yout adapter to your list view in fragment like this

```
SampAdapter ad=new SampAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.your_root_view, YourArrayObject);
```

if its not working change to base adapter and write your own Constructor with Context,YourArrayObject and try.

Comment: my heads going to explode XD

Comment: Sir the <Contact> turns red

Comment: sir how to i set my array object?

Comment: could you please explain more how to put my listview inside my fragment?

Comment: View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_d, container, false);
        ListView contentlistD = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ItemListView_D);
        NavItemListAdapter ad=new NavItemListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listviewd, YourArrayObject);
what to put in "yourarrayobject"?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you make a java class adapter to call the items

```
public class DListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DListView> {

    public DListViewAdapter(Context context, List<DListView> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.listviewd, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            // inflate the GridView item layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewd, parent, false);

            // initialize the view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.tvpoints = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.points);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // recycle the already inflated view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // update the item view
        DListView item = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.iconAdapter);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.titleAdapter);
        viewHolder.tvpoints.setText(item.pointsAdapter);

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivIcon;
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvDescription;
    }
}
```

create an listviewItem java class like this one i made for you :D

```
public class DListView {
    public final Drawable iconAdapter;
    public final String titleAdapter;
    public final String pointsAdapter;

    public DListView(Drawable icon, String title, String points) {
        this.iconAdapter = icon;
        this.titleAdapter = title;
        this.pointsAdapter = points;
    }
}
```

and create the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewD"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and i kinda forgot what to put at the fragment be right back on it :(

Comment: wait a minute you just used the link i posted >_<